# parsing XML file in PHP easiest way

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm searching for the easiest way to get some values from a XML file using PHP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oscam version="1.20-unstable_svn build r10649"   revision="10649" starttime="2015-05-27T06:41:07-0400" uptime="710700" readonly="0">
<reader label="Sky" status="OFF" caid="09C7">
    <emmstats totalwritten="0" totalskipped="0" totalblocked="0" totalerror="0">
        <emm type="unknown" result="error">0</emm>
        <emm type="unique" result="error">0</emm>
        <emm type="shared" result="error">0</emm>
        <emm type="global" result="error">0</emm>
        <emm type="unknown" result="written">0</emm>
        <emm type="unique" result="written">0</emm>
        <emm type="shared" result="written">0</emm>
        <emm type="global" result="written">0</emm>
        <emm type="unknown" result="skipped">0</emm>
        <emm type="unique" result="skipped">0</emm>
        <emm type="shared" result="skipped">0</emm>
        <emm type="global" result="skipped">0</emm>
        <emm type="unknown" result="blocked">0</emm>
        <emm type="unique" result="blocked">0</emm>
        <emm type="shared" result="blocked">0</emm>
        <emm type="global" result="blocked">0</emm>

    </emmstats>
    <ecmstats count="0" totalecm="0" lastaccess="">

    </ecmstats>
    <ecmhistory></ecmhistory>
  </reader>
</oscam>
```

For example I need to get "uptime" and "status" field.
I tried:

```
$oscam = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
$uptime = (int) $oscam['uptime']; 
$status = (string) $oscam->reader['status'];

echo $status;
```

Comment: SimpleXML or DOMDocument - personally I prefer DOMDocument : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php ... as an aside I've just discovered "let me Google that for you" links are blocked in comments ... probably for the best.

Comment: I edited code above.

Comment: Your code works fine https://eval.in/375811

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters said, there are a few possibilities. SimpleXML - as the name says - IMHO is the most simple one, as requested in your question.

It's quite easy then. Assuming, that your XML data is contained in the string variable `$xml`:

```
$oscam = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$uptime = (int) $oscam['uptime'];
$status = (string) $oscam->reader['status'];
```

Now, `$uptime` holds the value `710700` and `$status` holds `OFF`.

Whenever you get confused, you can always try something like `print_r($oscam)` to find out, how the XML is mapped to the `$oscam` object and hence where to find the data you need.

Comment: I edited code above, result -> no output when opening the script via Browser.

Comment: Hmm, strange... I tried with the very same code and got the correct output ("OFF"). Could you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning and see if some output is produced then? What version of PHP are you using?